# Leading zeros won´t paste when merging columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge, leading-zero

I need to use information of two columns to build numbers as below:

`-4 24296   -4.24296
-4  20320   -4.20320
-4  16356   -4.16356
-4  12410   -4.12410
-4  08500   -4.08500
-4  04619   -4.04619
-4  00739   -4.00739`

This is the routine I´m using to merge the values:

```
Range("R3").Select

Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & "." & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

The problem is that this routine is ignoring the leading zeros even though I made the program display them with:

```
Worksheets("Data").Columns("R").NumberFormat = "00000"
```

This is the output my program is giving me:

`-4 24296   -4.24296
-4  20320   -4.20320
-4  16356   -4.16356
-4  12410   -4.12410
-4  08500   -4.85000
-4  04619   -4.46190
-4  00739   -4.73900`

(Last three rows are wrong)

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Build numbers as numbers, not as text.

Comment: Display is not the same as value.  By changing the format to show leading zeroes, you've done nothing to the value itself in column "R"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & "." & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)` use this instead:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) - ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)/100000
```

Comment: The only risk I can see here is that the value in column R could exceed 5 positions. and then this would be incorrect.  May be better to find the length of the max column in R, and take 10^of that max length.  But if all known  values will be less than 99999, this is very clean.

Comment: @tigeravatar, This solves the leading zero problem, but causes another problem: I have Positive and Negative numbers in column Q. Will have to come up with an IF routine to sum when positive in column Q and subtract when negative in column Q.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) + Sgn(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)) * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)/100000` to solve the sign problem.

Comment: @tigeravatar, Thank you very much as well!